# Is it possible to control tabs(Hide/Visible) in Flutter programmatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have two tabs each with some data to be filled by the user. In Tab-1 (Personal Data) I have a form with some widgets where the user has to enter his personal details.

After filling all the details in the Tab-1 (form-1) only the Tab-2 (Medical History) should be navigated and visible. How to achieve this in Flutter?

Comment: You can dynamically replace the content. Please share more details or app wireframe

Comment: In tab-1 say a textform field widget is there if it is filled by th user and on pressing a raisedbutton the next tab(tab -2 with another text form field ) should be opened. Simply saying,  tab-2 data should not be visible and accssible until tab-1's form is filled.

Comment: why do you have tabs for such a requirement if you don't want it to be visible? Can you share the image/wireframe for better understanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this by maintaining the count of tab bar items to be displayed. 
Basically we have to create two `List<Widget>` which will depend on tab bar count to be displayed.

**Example:**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _tabBarCount = 1;

  List<Widget> getTabBarList() { // Tab Bar items displayed on the App Bar
    switch (_tabBarCount) {
      case 1:
        return [Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.search))];
      case 2:
        return [
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.file_download))
        ];
      default:
        return [];
    }
  }

  List<Widget> getTabScreen() { // Screens to be displayed on Tab Bar
    switch (_tabBarCount) {
      case 1:
        return [
          RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _tabBarCount = 2; // Click event, here tab bar count should increse, so that multiple tab bar can be visible.
            });
          }, child: Text('Save'),)
        ];
      case 2:
        return [
          Text('First Screen'),
          Text('Second Screen')
        ];
      default:
        return [];
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: _tabBarCount,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: getTabBarList(),
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: getTabScreen(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wonderful. It suits my requirement with few changes. Thanks a lot